# Supervisor 3.1.3 installed on Cento OS 6.4 hosted on DigitalOcean giving error while adding process

Tags: centos6, php5, cloud-hosting

I have live server on **Digital Ocean** with Cento OS 6.4 hosted. I am trying to install supervisor for the Laravel-5 processes. But, when I try to add the process it gives me error as undefined process. I have this in my `laravel.conf` file stored at `/etc/supervisord.d/`

```
[program:laravel]
command=/usr/local/bin/run_queue.sh
autostart=true 
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/www/html/laravel/queue.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/laravel/queue.out.log
```

This file is executable. I tried all possible things on all mediums. Is any one facing same problem??
Any help will be appreciated.

edit:
on running this i got :

```
sudo service supervisord restart
Shutting down supervisord:                                 [OK  ]
 Starting supervisord: /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages supervisor    /options.py:296: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
 'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
                                                   [FAILED]
```

Comment: What's the exact error message/messages from the log?

Comment: error log is empty. They are not created yet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the command?

command=/path/to/laravel/php artisan queue:work sqs --sleep=3 --tries=3 --daemon

Doc:
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#supervisor-configuration

I however do believe it's because it can't find the conf file.
have you tried this:
echo_supervisord_conf > supervisord.conf

sudo cp supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf

sudo mkdir /etc/supervisord.d/

sudo vi /etc/supervisord.conf

:

[include]
files = /etc/supervisord.d/*.conf
:

link: https://rayed.com/wordpress/?p=1496

if you only have the laravel worker, you could change the line to /etc/supervisord.d/laravel.conf